# I am unable to change the parameter using Gulp

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

I want to make it so that when new users refresh page, the version number increments by 1. So the build number variable = 1. So when you refresh page, the parameter changes to ?build=2.
Also the he file name must also change. So perhaps a random number of 4-5 characters. For instance: build-min-8be0d.js.

Here are the files.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5BrOt-jIaa-SEVaaURmSXZ6YVk

Answer (score 0):

you will have to use `gulp-rev` to get the random suffix with files, and for increasing number: keep that build-no in gulpfile, increment in watch task and use `gulp-replace` to replace it in html